# javacv webcam stream server

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I was wondering how would i be able to stream video over a tcp server using javacv.are there any tutorials on this so far i am capturing from usbwebcam. but i need to set up a server in order to grab it from my android.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but something like this should work for a simple RTP "server":

```
FrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("rtp://0.0.0.0:port", imageWidth, imageHeight, audioChannels);
recorder.setFormat("rtp");
recorder.setAudioCodec(...);
recorder.setVideoCodec(...);
// etc.
recorder.start();
while (...) {
    recorder.record(image);
    recorder.record(ShortBuffer.wrap(audioSamples));
}
```